# In Matlab, how to solve an equation originating in a function?

Tags: matlab, function, equation, symbolic-math

How do I easiest solve an equation=0 with a function as a parameter?

My function with one input variable is called potd(angle), with one output variable, potNRGderiv. I tried:

syms x

solve(potd(x))

This gave me error: Undefined function 'sind' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Have you got any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`solve` is the wrong avenue here, unless your function can be rewritten as a simple equation.  `solve` uses [muPAD functions](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/mupadfunctionlist.html) which is why you can do `solve(sin(x))` but not `solve(sind(x))`.  You can, of course, just do the conversion yourself.

If your function is more complicated or you'd rather not rewrite it, look into [fsolve](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html):

`x = fsolve(@myfun,x0)`

Where x0 is your initial guess - i.e. myfun(x0) is close to 0 - and `myfun` is a function which takes x and returns a single output. Depending on what your function does, you may have to adjust the options using `optimoptions` (tolerance, step size, etc) to get a good result.